# Disk not showing data created when being used by other OS (Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with Windows 8 )

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 8. I have 1 TB hard disk that has three partitions: one for Ubuntu (sdb 1) another for Windows (sdb 2) and a third partition (sdb 3) for data that I want to use from both OS and share data among them

[image: gparted screenshot]

However, currently I cannot see data saved from Windows in Ubuntu and vice versa. I did change partition to NTFS and FAT 32 also but did not share data screen shot of partition attached.

How could I share data among Ubuntu and Windows with one shared partition? I am new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by Windows' fast startup:

> When you shut down a computer with Fast Startup enabled, Windows locks down the Windows hard disk. You won’t be able to access it from other operating systems if you have your computer configured to dual-boot. Even worse, if you boot into another OS and then access or change anything on the hard disk (or partition) that the hibernating Windows installation uses, it can cause corruption. If you’re dual booting, it’s best not to use Fast Startup or Hibernation at all.

I disabled fast startup from **Control Panel > System & Security > power options > what power button does** and unchecked the checkbox,
and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you could use extexplore from Windows, and format your shared partition with ext4...

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/

But your method should work also.  To help diagnose, are you doing chkdsk on Windows, or fsck on Linux?  Are you mounting read-write in Linux?  Is there any trouble with your other partitions?

Comment: i did reformatted to NTFS and this works fine now

Answer (score 0):

The third partition is the right path. I set mine up as NTFS. You need to edit your file `/etc/fstab` and insert the Windows partitions with appropriate sharing access. Here is what mine looks like:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=113f9955-a064-4ce2-9cae-74f2a9518550 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=b4512bc6-0ec8-4b17-9edd-88db0f031332 none            swap    sw              0       0
#UUID=D656-F2A8 /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   0
# Windows drives C, D & E
UUID=F03ED48E3ED44F6A /mnt/d    ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8         0 0
UUID=5CCC5867CC583E08 /mnt/c    ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,x-gvfs-show 0     0
UUID=F2C2ACE4C2ACADF3 /mnt/e    ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,x-gvfs-show 0     0
UUID=D656-F2A8  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   0
```

Besides using `blkid` as recommended in the file above, you can use this command:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,UUID,MODEL
NAME        FSTYPE  LABEL                  MOUNTPOINT          SIZE UUID                                 MODEL
sda                                                          931.5G                                      HGST HTS721010A9
├─sda1      vfat    ESP                                        500M 9478-B6E2                            
├─sda2                                                         128M                                      
├─sda3      ntfs    HGST_Win10             /mnt/d              919G F03ED48E3ED44F6A                     
├─sda4      ntfs    WINRETOOLS                                 450M 221A463E1A460F6B                     
└─sda5      ntfs    Image                                     11.4G 38D4470BD446CB38                     
sdb                                                           14.4G                                      STORE N GO      
├─sdb1      ntfs    usbdata                /media/rick/usbda   6.4G 7C7138CA3671C2BF                     
├─sdb2                                                           1M                                      
├─sdb3      vfat    usbboot                                    244M 49EB-DCAA                            
├─sdb4      iso9660 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64 /media/rick/Ubunt   1.4G 2018-01-21-07-51-27-00               
└─sdb5      ext4    casper-rw              /media/rick/caspe   6.4G 4c46a63f-b96c-43b0-ac19-2664474cae5d 
sr0                                                           1024M                                      DVD+/-RW DW316  
nvme0n1                                                        477G                                      Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs                                               450M 7040FA5240FA1F12                     
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat                           /boot/efi            99M D656-F2A8                            
├─nvme0n1p3                                                     16M                                      
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs    NVMe_Win10             /mnt/c            391.2G 5CCC5867CC583E08                     
├─nvme0n1p5 ext4    NVMe_Ubuntu_16.0                          44.6G f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b 
├─nvme0n1p6 swap    Linux Swap             [SWAP]              7.9G b4512bc6-0ec8-4b17-9edd-88db0f031332 
├─nvme0n1p7 ntfs    Shared_WSL+Linux       /mnt/e                9G F2C2ACE4C2ACADF3                     
└─nvme0n1p8 ext4    Ubuntu18.04            /                  23.7G 113f9955-a064-4ce2-9cae-74f2a9518550
```

Then update your `/etc/fstab` with the Windows drives you want auto-mounted on boot.